# Adding on click events to buttons in MVC Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

I've been trying to call a javascript function from a button click, and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I've searched for similar questions and followed the answers, but the button click is still not calling the function.

The following code is in my `.cshtml` page. First, I create the button

```
<input type="button" id="myButton" onclick="Save()"/>
```

And I have a function on the same page

```
<script> function Save() { ..do stuff here } </script>
```

This function never gets called. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Spaces are not allowed in front of tag names. I think that is what's causing the problem here.

Comment: Just write `$('#myButton').click(function {alert("hi");});` and remove `onclick="Save()"` from button

Answer (score 4):

Here you can do like this way:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#myButton").click(function() {
        alert("button clicked.");
      });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" id="myButton" value="test"/>
```

Comment: If it helped you, then please accept this an answer. and also check how [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/342092)